# What is the graphical representation of the instantaneous rate of change

Tags: calculus

What is the graphical representation of the instantaneous rate of change? I do not get how to answer this question. Isn't it 2 separate things?

Comment: Why do you think it's two separate things? It's just asking what it represents graphically.

Comment: But there is no other question attached to it. I don't get how to explain there relations

Comment: Hint: If the average rate of change is the secant line, what would the instantaneous rate of change be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instantaneous rate of change is equivalent to the derivative.

At a single point on a function $f(x)$ the instantaneous rate of change is the **slope of the tangent line at that point**.

For an entire function, the instantaneous rate of change at a point $(x, f(x))$ is $f'(x)$ (the derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $y$